# Elasticsearch IO wait when using dense_vector field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elasticsearch 7.15.2

While testing the performances of various types of queries using the dense_vector field type we noticed that a significant amount of time is spent loading the dense_vector from the disk.

We observed the following behaviors :

- Using the dense_vectors in a rescorer we noticed that by incrementing the window_size parameter we have higher spikes in disk reads (and therefore io wait) each time a new query is executed.
- When executing twice the same query (and therefore loading the same vectors in the rescorer) we have a spike in disk reads with the first query and pretty much no disk usage with the second one. We can also see that the time dedicated to the rescorer is significantly lower on the second query (we evaluated the time taken by the rescorer using the [profile api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html)).
- When using smaller indexes that can fit in memory this issue is visible only when executing the first few queries. Once most of the vectors have been "seen" by the rescorer the disk usage becomes negligible and queries are faster.

Since in # [Performance and storage of the dense_vector type](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/performance-and-storage-of-the-dense-vector-type/265850) it is explained that elasticsearch compresses the dense vectors when storing them we tried reducing the number of decimals used to represent the vectors, this resulted in less disk space used but in practice no difference in the disk read spikes that are slowing down the queries.

Is there a way besides reducing the window_size parameter to avoid the high disk wait when using the dense_vector field?

Comment: We're not seeing what they claim in linked discussion as `4*dims+4` in our case. We are using 1024 dimension vectors and based on the index size it is nowhere near 4 KB but rather 25 KB per vector which is approx the same amount if you save 1024 floating point values in a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

Not surprising in that version of ES . I would upgrade to ES 8.0 and use indexed - dense vectors , which uses Lucene KNN implementation ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html#index-vectors-knn-search)

Comment: We are aware of the improvements es8 brings, however the functionality is in technical preview (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search-api.html#knn-search-api) and does not yet support filtering search results, which we need (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#approximate-knn-limitations).